# Make an array at compile time

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that looks like this

```
class Foo 
{
public:
   template<class T> 
   A(T * ptr) { ptr_ = reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr_);} 

   template<class T>
   T * get() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr_);}

private:
  void * ptr_;
};
```

At compile time, I know exactly what elements are going to be in my array. Is there a way I can annotate this class such that an array of Foo pointers knows which type it should get?

Basically I want to call `Foo[i]<T>->apply()` and not have to look up the type at runtime, since it should know at compile time what kind of object it is.

P.S. Please don't suggest virtual functions, I know they are a valid solution but I want to know if this is possible because I do have all type information at compile time.

Comment: Since C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays, *all* arrays are created (and their size known) at compile-time. Also templates is a pure compile-time thing, the type of `T` will *always* be known at compile-time.

Comment: By the way, your constructor and `get` function allows you to break strict aliasing very easily. For type-erasure there are other constructs you can use (like `std::variant` or `std::any`).

Comment: Yes but at run time I still need to get<T> with T being the correct type, is there a way to call get without needing the type, since everything is indeed known at compile time?

Comment: Make the whole class a template? By using a `void *` you explicitly *erase* the type information. And can you please elaborate on the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need something like this?

Comment: If you declare the pointer as `T * _ptr`, then they are of the correct type (and you do not need the `reinterpret_cast`'s). To me this seems like the obvious answer to your question, did I miss something?

Comment: But then I would need a separate array for Foo<A> and Foo<B>. I'm trying to make a collection of objects that call a specific type of handler, depending on the class. Since these handlers are known at compile time, I want to get the handler class back. The problem I'm trying to solve is the avoid virtual functions for types I already know at compile time.

Comment: @nielsen, yes because then Foo would need to be templated right?

Comment: @AmanGupta it would help if you could update your question to show an example of what exactly you are trying to solve

Comment: @RemyLebeau added some more context

Comment: So you probably want `std::variant<Foo<A>, Foo<B>>` for your collection of `Foo`.

Comment: @Jarod42, std::variant AFAIK uses virtual functions

Comment: @AmanGupta the added info is not very helpful. But in any case, elements of an array must be the same type. Templating the class as a whole, and then declaring the array as holding elements of a particular specialization of that template, is the correct solution. Trying to apply a template to individual array elements at the time of access is a recipe for disaster. Otherwise, you have to use polymorphism (virtual methods) which you said you don't want to do (why?).

Comment: Maybe then `std::tuple<Foo<A>, Foo<B>>`?

Comment: Is there a type here: `A(T * ptr) { ptr_ = reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr_);} `? Looks like the second instance of `ptr_` should not have the trailing underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is as follows:

You want to have some kind of table/array which contains object pointers and member function pointers to the corresponding objects. Later you want to call that "pairs" without any virtual function in between.

Maybe you can start with this approach:

```
struct A 
{
    void Foo() { std::cout << "A Foo" << std::endl; }
    void Bar() { std::cout << "A Bar" << std::endl; }
};

struct B 
{
    void Do() { std::cout << "B Do " << std::endl; }
    void Go() { std::cout << "B Go " << std::endl; }
};

    template < typename T, auto MEM_PTR >
void Call( void* obj)
{
    (((T*)obj)->*(MEM_PTR))();
}

using OBJ_FUNC_PAIR = std::pair< void* , void(*)(void*) >;

A a;
B b;

std::array< OBJ_FUNC_PAIR ,4 > arr
{
    {
        { (void*)&a, &Call<A, &A::Foo>},
            { (void*)&a, &Call<A, &A::Bar>},
            { (void*)&b, &Call<B, &B::Do > },
            { (void*)&b, &Call<B, &B::Go > }
    }
};

int main()
{
    for ( auto& pair: arr )
    {
        (*pair.second)( pair.first );
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you declare a template parameter "auto"?

Comment: @AmanGupta: You can also declare the template without "auto" as a specialization with the member function pointer parameters if you can't use C++17. But your question was tagged C++ and we have 2019 :-)